# inserting artificial data into SQL Server indexes

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way in SQL Server to create an index with data that doesn't exist in the table itself? for example, create an index that points to the primary key, but where each row also includes custom data that the DBA inserts into the index, where this data does not really exist in the columns themselves.

Comment: No. SQL Server isn't dBase, you cannot *insert* "random" data into indexes. SQL Server can index many columns - up to 900 bytes per index entry - but anything that you want to have in an index **must be** part of the table being indexed

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to do but it seems like you're thinking a bit more physical implementation than logical design.  What you describe is a related table, not an index.  Indexes may be used to make it work/enforce integrity with a reasonable performance but they are not storage mechanisms in the first instance (covering indexes aside).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is bypass a limitation of fulltext search. As far as I could find online, fulltext will look for "word*" but not for "*word". I thought if I could index every word twice, once in its normal form and once in reverse - and manipulate the strings that users search for - that might work. But storing every single string twice, once normal and once reversed, and then storing them again as a fulltext index, sounds like an incredible waste of space.

Comment: An index is a "waste of space" in the sense it generally does store the desired value twice.  Have you considered an index on a computed column?  That might do the trick.

Comment: @user884248 As long as the expression is deterministic you can create a computed column and index that. Or an indexed view, but you should probably ask a new question about the root issue you are having with full text search. Not your proposed solution. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/145673)

Comment: Thank you all for the computed column idea, I'll try it out. Martin - I know, but I had already asked about this issue here in the past, and from what I understand, there is no solution except changing SQL Server to another database which supports this.